# How to calculate number of hours between current date-time and given date-time in DAX(power bi)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

How to calculate number of hours between current date-time and given date-time in DAX(power bi).
After calculating, need to group them in two groups, based on the 4 categories, also exclude time of weekend.

IF
{
Category 1
1st Group - If Difference between current date-time and given date-time is less than 6 hours.
2nd Group - IF difference between current date-time and given date-time is more than 24 hours.
}

IF
{
Category 2
1st Group - If Difference between current date-time and given date-time is less than 6 hours.
2nd Group - IF difference between current date-time and given date-time is more than 24 hours.
}

IF
{
Category 3
1st Group - If Difference between current date-time and given date-time is less than 6 hours
2nd Group - IF difference between current date-time and given date-time is more than 74 hours
}

IF
{
Category 4
1st Group - If Difference between current date-time and given date-time is less than 6 hours
2nd Group - IF difference between current date-time and given date-time is more than 74 hours
}

Comment: What is difference between Category 1&2 and 3&4? Where from the Given Date coming?

Comment: Hi @mkRabbani Thank you for your attention Difference between Category 1 and 2 is like they are state of the ticket, e.g. Category 1- Assigned to any agent, Category 2- Action required by the agent on that ticket. Given date, I fetched from the tool which on which team is working. It is in LA time zone I add the number of hours to match it with local time.